why $H(Y|X) \le H(Y)$
Say we have 100 cards, where 98 of them have both faces white, one has both faces black, and the last one has one face white and the other black.
If I ask "what face am I looking at" we have $p(F) \sim Be(0.985)$, because we have 3 black faces and 197 white faces. Therefore, $H(F) \approx 0.0808$
Now, say I know the other face is black. Then $p(F|F'=black) \sim Be(0.5)$, $H(F|F'=black) = 1$
So, to me, it seems that additional information increased the entropy, but information theory clearly states that $H(Y|X) \le H(Y)$, so knowing the color of the other face should not make me more uncertain
So, my conclusion is that I'm drastically misunderstanding/missing something, any idea? Should I consider the average conditional entropy instead of a specific case?...

You lost me in the second paragraph: what is the probability distribution governing "faces I am looking at" and how does 3/(197+3) work out to 0.99??

@whuber yup sorry that was a typo... I was referring to something like "take the cards, shuffle and flip them however you want, take a random one, and tell me the color of the face you are looking at"

$H(Y|X) \ne H(Y|X=x_0)$
Instead, as wiki states, "Note that $H(Y|X)$ is the result of averaging $H(Y|X=x)$ over all possible values $x$ that $X$ may take.".
You may also find this post useful; it is directly related.
Note also that, in your first paragraph $p(F) \sim Be(0.985)$, which does not really change anything, but ...

thanks for the spot, that was a bad typo, the entropy was actually calculated with $Be(0.985)$... regarding the answer, I see where my confusion comes from, I probably too used to $p(X|Y)$ which implies $p(X|Y=y)$, so I've probably messed up the notations (thanks for the answer)

Entropy uses nasty "conditioning" conventions/notation that can be confusing
One of the tricky things about entropy is that it refers to expected values of functions that are themselves based on probability densities.  They have the general form $H = \mathbb{E}[-\log p_Y(Y)]$, where $p_Y$ is some probability density/mass function and $Y$ is a random variable/vector used in the argument (the expectation operates on this random variable).  This form has two probability functions entering in two different places --- one as the argument inside the expected value, and one as the distribution used in taking the expected value.  We can write the entropy in explicit form (showing two probability densities in the expression) as:
$$H = \mathbb{E}[-\log p_Y(Y)] = - \int \limits_\mathscr{Y} p_Y(y) \log p_Y(y) \ dy.$$
Because there are two probability density functions used here, this means that there are two types of "conditioning" that could potentially enter into the calculation.  One option is actual probabilistic conditioning to get a conditional expectation of the function of interest, which would give a quantity of the form:
$$\mathbb{E}[-\log p_Y(Y) | X] = - \int \limits_\mathscr{Y} p_{Y|X}(y|X) \log p_Y(y) \ dy
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad 
\text{(Function of } X \text{)}.$$
The other option is conditioning used in the probability density function that is used inside the expectation operator, which would give a quantity of the form:
$$\mathbb{E}[-\log p_{Y|X}(Y|X)] = - \int \limits_\mathscr{Y} \int \limits_\mathscr{X} p_{X,Y}(x,y) \log p_{Y|X}(y|x) \ dx \ dy
\quad \quad \quad \quad
\text{(Fixed constant)}.$$
The conditional entropy refers to the second of these quantities, but it uses a nasty notation that writes the quantity as $H(Y|X)$, which gives the (false) impression that it is referring to something like the first quantity.  Note that unlike in standard notation for probability/moments, the notational conditioning on $X$ does not mean that the quantity is a function of the random variable $X$ (which would be the first quantity).  Moreover, the law of total probability does not apply to entropy:
$$H(Y) \neq H(Y|X) = \int \limits_\mathscr{X} p_X(x) H(Y|X=x) \ dx.$$

Thank for the answer, I agree, very confusing notation… so to answer the last question, I should also compute the entropy of the “white” case, and sum them weighting them by $p(F’)$ (so something like $E_{F’}[ H(F|F’=f’)]$)
